# Retornando uma lista usando select new com LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Eu consigo fazer isso:

```
var filial = (from f in base.EntityContext.vw_filial
              select f).ToList<vw_filial>();
```

Mas, eu quero fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
var filial = (from f in base.EntityContext.vw_filial
     select new
     {
         COD_FILIAL = f.COD_FILIAL,
         CGCCPF = f.CGCCPF,
         NM_FILIAL = f.NM_FILIAL,
         NMC_FILIAL = f.NMC_FILIAL,
         END_FILIAL = f.END_FILIAL,
         BAI_FILIAL = f.BAI_FILIAL,
         CEP_FILIAL = f.CEP_FILIAL,
         CID_FILIAL = f.CID_FILIAL,
         UF_FILIAL = f.UF_FILIAL
     }).ToList<vw_filial>();
```

No `select new` contém todos os atributos da classe `vw_filial`. Mas, o visual Studio me retorna o seguinte erro:

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' não contém uma definição
>   para 'ToList' e que o método
>   'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.ToList(System.Linq.ParallelQuery)'
>   tem alguns argumentos errados'.
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definiton
>   for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.ToList(System.Linq.ParallelQuery)'
>   has some invalid arguments.

O que eu preciso é pegar o retorno da expressão, e armazená-la em uma lista do tipo `vw_filiais`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No `select new` passe o tipo do objeto que você quer retornar na lista.

```
var filial = (from f in base.EntityContext.vw_filial
     select new vw_filial
     {
         COD_FILIAL = f.COD_FILIAL,
         CGCCPF = f.CGCCPF,
         NM_FILIAL = f.NM_FILIAL,
         NMC_FILIAL = f.NMC_FILIAL,
         END_FILIAL = f.END_FILIAL,
         BAI_FILIAL = f.BAI_FILIAL,
         CEP_FILIAL = f.CEP_FILIAL,
         CID_FILIAL = f.CID_FILIAL,
         UF_FILIAL = f.UF_FILIAL
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Realmente, solucionou o meu problema.

Comment: E se o select retornar mais de uma tabela, digo quando faz um join, qual objeto ele retornaria ?? porque teria uma mistura de entidades ai.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso o mais simples seria assim:

```
var filial = (from f in base.EntityContext.vw_filial
     select f).ToList();
```

Ou inline assim:

```
var filial = base.EntityContext.vw_filial.ToList();
```